# If $R$ is $\text{UFD},$ then $R[X,Y]$ is $\text{UFD}.$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be commutative ring with $1.$ Suppose $R$ is $\text{UFD}.$ Could anyone advise me on how to prove $R[X,Y]$ is $\text{UFD}\ ?$ Thank you.

Comment: Do you already know that UFD $\,R\,\Rightarrow\,$ UFD  $\,R[x]\,?\ \ $ If so, do you see how to apply that inductively?

Comment: Bill, this was my hint.

Comment: @Dietrich Indeed (your answer did not appear till I reloaded the page). But the question is still pertinent anyhow, since the OP may not know the result.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a UFD then $R[x]$ is a UFD, see any textbook in algebra. Now set $S=R[x]$ and consider $S[y]=R[x,y]$. Also, the Laurent ring $R[x,x^{-1}]$ is again a UFD.